# Refresh an image if new image is found

Tags: javascript, image, function, refresh

I am refreshing images from webcams every second on an app. The problem I have is if for a few seconds an image is not retrieved from the camera (which happens frequently) I end up with a broken image. I would like to have it so that it only refreshes if and when a new image is found.

So far I have

```
var int_time = setInterval(function() {
   var myImageElement = document.getElementById('myImage');
   myImageElement.src = '<%= EVERCAM_API %>cameras/<%= @camera["id"] %>/snapshot.jpg?api_id=<%=  current_user.api_id %>&api_key=<%= current_user.api_key %>&rand=' + new Date().getTime();
}, 1000);
```

Is it possible to stop the refresh if the image not retrieved?

Comment: handle it in the `onerror` callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following snippet will help.

**Solution:**

1) Create a dynamic image object

2) Bind onload event

3) set src of dynamically created image object to the desired new image link

4) on success of loading dynamic image, replace original tag or set the src of original image tag to the latest image link

This will avoid problem of broken image

**Code:**

```
var int_time;
(function(){
    var el = document.getElementById('myImage');
    function loadImage () {
        var img = new Image()
          , src = '<%= EVERCAM_API %>cameras/<%= @camera["id"] %>/snapshot.jpg?api_id=<%=  current_user.api_id %>&api_key=<%= current_user.api_key %>&rand=' + new Date().getTime();;
        img.onload = function() {
          if (!! el.parent)
            el.parent.replaceChild(img, el)
          else
            el.src = src;
        }
        img.src = src;
    }
    int_time = setInterval(loadImage, 1000);
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Save it in a variable and then check the variable for its contents, but I cannot tell you what the api returns if the image could not be fetched. You need to fix that on your own I assume false here...

```
var int_time = setInterval(function() {
    var myImageElement = document.getElementById('myImage');
    var newImage = '<%= EVERCAM_API %>cameras/<%= @camera["id"] %>/snapshot.jpg?api_id=<%=  current_user.api_id %>&api_key=<%= current_user.api_key %>&rand=' + new Date().getTime();
    if(newImage != false) { //Here you have to build an expression if the image is valid
        myImageElement.src = newImage;
    }
}, 1000);
```